# Bypass the faulty gcc "-mcygwin" argument, when building a library on python-3.4 on windows, through cygwin

Tags: windows, gcc, build, cygwin, python-3.4

I have the following problem:

I want to build an external library of python on **Windows** through a script that uses gcc.

When the script reaches the command:
`python setup.py build --compiler=cygwin`, the following command is generated (that crashes):

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe -mcygwin -mdll -O -Wall -Inauty -Isrc -IC:\Python34\include -IC:\Python34\include -c src/nautywrap.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-3.4\Release\src\nautywrap.o -O4 -fPIC
```

One suggestion is whether, I could get rid of the *-mcygwin* flag and apply other arguments.
(This flag is deprecated -- raises an error: 
see [gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-mcygwin](http://cygwin.cygwin.narkive.com/EfxZ79Fh/gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-option-mcygwin))

I am using *Python 3.4 64-bit* (which **cannot** change..), in a *windows_7_x64* environment with cygwin/gcc installed. I can only access the library of the code through the script, so manual code changes, unfortunately, do not offer a solution.

A simple answer could concern the case I could append any arguments by the command:
 `python setup.py build --compiler=cygwin`, in order for ordinary python arguments for the gcc to be omitted and mine to be written on top.

Comment: do you _really_ need cygwin? or could do with mingw?

Comment: I am trying to see what happens when compiling with cygwin. Currently mingw is successful but raises 4 GB memory overhead when importing a small library.. For that error you can see here: [Memory leak loading python modules compiled by MinGW](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/271)

Comment: use the cross compiler https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-10/msg00028.html

Comment: @matzeri I am not sure what your instruction means (can you  be a little more detailed?), but as far as it is the mingw gcc want it have the same issue when importing on python, as I mentioned above on comments?